# Calling a method after returning to the first activity

Tags: java, android

I am a complete newbie in the coding world. Currently, I am trying to develop a quiz app and am stuck with an issue. A little brief:- There are 2 activities 1. `Questions` activity 2. `Score` activity. What I want is to display score after each question and change the question when I return to the `Questions` activity. I have created a method in `Questions` activity named `ChangeQuestion()`.

The issue I am facing is when the 1st question is answered correctly, the score activity is shown and instead of loading question 2, the question 1 is displayed again.

I am not sure if I am making any sense. Please let me know if any clarification/information is required.

- `Changequestion` method

[image]

- Part where `ChnangeQuestion` method is called

[image]

Comment: Is your quesNum a static variable?

Comment: No my quesNum is not static variable

Comment: Then do it "static". It will work.

Comment: Nope... Doesn't work

Comment: Or while pausing you can add the current value to a static variable of other class and then onResume you can fetch it from there.

Comment: why cannot you change question before moving to scoreActivity?. If you do when you come back 2nd question will be sustained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you `quesNum` variable will lose its current value when your activity is destroyed and recreated, so it gets its initial value (which maps to the first question) every time you leave the Question activity and come back.

So, you need to save the value of the current question before the Question activity is destroyed. There are several ways to do this.

One of which you can save it permanently using the [`SharedPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

In your Question activity

initiate the shared preference in `onResume()` method

```
SharedPreferences mPreferences;
int quesNum;

onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySahredPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    quesNum = sharedPrefs.getInt("CURRENT_QUES", 0); // <<< getting the current question number from the shared preference, and set the default question number to 0
    
}
```

And whenever you change the current question value, set it in the `SharedPreference`, or you can do that in the Question activity `onPause()` method

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = mPreferences.edit();
    preferencesEditor.putInt("CURRENT_QUES", quesNum); // <<<<<<<< setting the current question value to the shared preference
    preferencesEditor.apply();

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Solving it by reserving the value of `quesNum` into the `Score` activity with `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()` and return it back to `Question` activity via `onActivityResult()`

So change `startActivity()` at the Questions activity to  `startActivityForResult()`, and put the current question value `quesNum` to the intent.

```
public class QuestionsActivity ... {
    
    public static final int CODE = 101;
    
    private void checckAnswer(...) {
        // ....
        intent.putExtra("QUES_NUM", quesNum);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {
            quesNum = data.getExtras().getInt("QUES_NUM");
        }


    }
}
```

In the `Score` activity, use the same intent you sent by the Questions activity by using `getIntent()`, and this intent already contains the current question which was stored in `quesNum` in `Question` activity.

```
public class ScoreActivity ... {
    
    // ....

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
    
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

In `Score` activity, after the `Handler` timer is up, you start a brand-new intent using intent constructor that will result in resetting the `questNum` to the first question, instead you need to `setResult()` within the handler.

Also you no longer need to `setResult()` outside the handler, because you already need some delay provided by the handler.

You also need to add `finish()` after `setResult`

So the Score activity code will be:

```
public class ScoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Button score5k;
    private Button score10k;
    private Button score20k;
    private int scoreholder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
        score5k = (Button) findViewById(R.id.score1);
        score10k = (Button) findViewById(R.id.score2);
        score20k = (Button) findViewById(R.id.score3);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int score = extras.getInt("Score");
        int question = extras.getInt("QUES_NUM");

        if (extras != null) {
            if (score == 1) {
                score5k.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                if (score == 2) {
                    score5k.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    score10k.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    if (score == 3) {
                        score5k.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                        score10k.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                        score20k.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    }
                }

            } else {

            }

        }

//        Intent intent = getIntent();
//        intent.putExtra("Quesnumber", question);
//        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);


        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(ScoreActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
//                startActivity(intent);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
                finish();
            }
        }, 4000);

    }

}
```

In `Question` Activity you're using the wrong key of the Question number, so replace

```
quesNum = data.getExtras().getInt("Quesnumber");
```

With

```
quesNum = data.getExtras().getInt("QUES_NUM");
```

In checkAnswer() method you call `changeQuestion()` after both branches of the `if/else statement`, but you actually want it only in the `else` branch, so move it to the `else` branch as below

```
private void checkAnswer(int selectedOption, View view) {

    if (selectedOption == questionList.get(quesNum).getCorrectAns()) {
        //Right answer

        ((Button) view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
        score++;
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Score", score);
        intent.putExtra("QUES_NUM", quesNum);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);


    } else {
        //Wrong answer
        ((Button) view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));

        switch (questionList.get(quesNum).getCorrectAns()) {
            case 1:
                option1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
            case 2:
                option2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
            case 3:
                option3.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
            case 4:
                option4.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
        }
        changeQuestion();
    }

}
```

The entire `Question` activity with these changes will be

```
public class QuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView question;
    public Button option1;
    public Button option2;
    public Button option3;
    public Button option4;
    private List<Question> questionList;
    private int score;
    private int quesNum;
    public static final int CODE = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question2);
//        setting buttons and text view. Linking with layout file
        question = findViewById(R.id.question);
        option1 = findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option2 = findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option3 = findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option4 = findViewById(R.id.option4);
        score = 0;

        option1.setOnClickListener(this);
        option2.setOnClickListener(this);
        option3.setOnClickListener(this);
        option4.setOnClickListener(this);

        getQuestionList();
    }

    private void getQuestionList() {

        questionList = new ArrayList<>();
        questionList.add(new Question("Question 1", "A", "B", "C", "D", 2));
        questionList.add(new Question("Question 2", "B", "C", "D", "A", 2));
        questionList.add(new Question("Question 3", "C", "D", "A", "B", 2));
        questionList.add(new Question("Question 4", "D", "B", "A", "C", 2));
        questionList.add(new Question("Question 5", "A", "C", "B", "D", 2));
        questionList.add(new Question("Question 6", "C", "B", "A", "D", 2));

        setQuestion();
    }

    private void setQuestion() {

        question.setText(questionList.get(0).getQuestion());
        option1.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionA());
        option2.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionB());
        option3.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionC());
        option4.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionD());
        quesNum = 0;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int selectedOption = 0;

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.option1:
                selectedOption = 1;
                break;

            case R.id.option2:
                selectedOption = 2;
                break;
            case R.id.option3:
                selectedOption = 3;
                break;

            case R.id.option4:
                selectedOption = 4;
                break;
        }

        checkAnswer(selectedOption, view);
    }

    private void checkAnswer(int selectedOption, View view) {

        if (selectedOption == questionList.get(quesNum).getCorrectAns()) {
            //Right answer

            ((Button) view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
            score++;
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Score", score);
            intent.putExtra("QUES_NUM", quesNum);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);


        } else {
            //Wrong answer
            ((Button) view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));

            switch (questionList.get(quesNum).getCorrectAns()) {
                case 1:
                    option1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    option2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    option3.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    option4.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    break;
            }
            changeQuestion();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            quesNum = data.getExtras().getInt("QUES_NUM");
            changeQuestion();
        }


    }


    public void changeQuestion() {

        if (quesNum < questionList.size() - 1) {
            quesNum++;
            playAnim(question, 0, 0);
            playAnim(option1, 0, 1);
            playAnim(option2, 0, 2);
            playAnim(option3, 0, 3);
            playAnim(option4, 0, 4);

        } else {
            //Display Score
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Score", score);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);

        }

    }

    private void playAnim(final View view, final int value, final int viewNum) {
        view.animate().alpha(value).scaleX(value).scaleY(value).setDuration(500).setStartDelay(100)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

            }

            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                if (value == 0) {
                    switch (viewNum) {
                        case 0:
                            ((TextView) view).setText(questionList.get(quesNum).getQuestion());
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            ((Button) view).setText(questionList.get(quesNum).getOptionA());
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ((Button) view).setText(questionList.get(quesNum).getOptionB());
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            ((Button) view).setText(questionList.get(quesNum).getOptionC());
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            ((Button) view).setText(questionList.get(quesNum).getOptionD());
                            break;

                    }

                    if (viewNum != 0) {

                        ((Button) view).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#4848FE")));
                    }

                    playAnim(view, 1, viewNum);
                } else {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but implementing your solution leads to app crash... Maybe I did something wrong... M not sure what.. is there any easy solution?

Comment: @VipulChaturvedi there must be something I can't see in the provided code.. I guess you can try the code I provided in onResume() into onCreate() ... There is another solution to send the quesnNum to Score activity and send it back to Question activity

Comment: Yes... Maybe I can send the quesNum to score activity and fetch it back.. I haven't tried that... Thanks for the suggestion.. will let you know if that works.

Comment: Nope... Still doesn't work. Sorry. Let me know if you have any other idea. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: @VipulChaturvedi please check updated answer in `UPDATE` section ..

Comment: Hi Zain... I have already tried this solution before posting the issue here but it doesn't work... Maybe I need to share my whole code so that you guys can help me in a better way. Let me know if I can share my whole code with you in personal so that you can help me in a better way.

Comment: Hi Vipul, there might be something wrong, you can share it on any online git repositories .. hopefully can find something

Comment: Hi Zain, I have added my whole code on github. please have a look and let me know where I went wrong.
https://github.com/Vipulchatur7/Myapp/issues/1

Comment: @VipulChaturvedi please check updated answer in `UPDATE 2`  section.. I tested it in local environment and works .. if you found it solve your problem please mark it as the correct answer .. thank you

Comment: Hi Zain, Thank you very much. Thank you for solving my error. This will be my very first app. It works